# db:create misreports database existence

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After creating a new site with commands

```
rails new board --skip-bundle
...
rake db:create
```

I have message like "XXXXX already exists" which is not consistent and indicates that something goes wrong.

Reproducing:

```
rails new board --skip-bundle 
...
$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
FATAL:  database "boardio" does not exist

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

If to try to create db then:

```
$ rake db:create
boardio already exists
```

It says here "exists". It just said "does not exist":
Why rake gives a wrong message? What is going wrong?
After this migration seems runs OK:

```
$ rake db:migrate
==  CreateMyTables: migrating =================================================
-- create_table("users")
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create ........column "users.id"
.............
```

Details about versions:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]

$ rails --version
Rails 3.1.3
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more, I'm not sure what's causing this odd behavior. I would recommend dropping and creating all your databases if this happens again:

```
rake db:drop:all && rake db:create:all
```

Answer (score 0):

The "does not exist" error led me to use an external tool to drop the db.

Then, to get rid of the "already exists" error that persisted, I renamed  "schema.rb" to "old_broken_db_schema.rb".

This allowed me to create and migrate the db.